# Could not locate /WEB-INF/lib/ directory to install Geoserver extensions in OSGEOLIVE 12

Tags: geoserver, extensions, osgeo-live

[image: This is the directory, but i didn't find geoserver directory]

I am not able to locate  in /var/lib/Tomcat8/webapps, the geoserver directory where i could paste my extensions file.
The above picture is the directory where i reached and i could find nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer on OSGEOLIVE uses Jetty - have a look in `/usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.X/webapps/geoserver` (where X is the version you are using).